# Append to existing TeamCity parameter

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

Is it possible to append some value to existing TeamCity configuration parameter from custom build script using service message?

I tried these options:

---

Step 1 (Command Line - Custom script - external):

`echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='par' value='%par% added']"`

Step 2 (Command Line - Custom script - inline):

`echo "%par%"  # %par%`

---

Step 1 (Command Line - Custom script - external):

`echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='par' value='par added']"`

Step 2 (Command Line - Custom script - inline):

`echo "%par%"  # par added`

---

Step 1 (Command Line - Custom script - external):

`echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='par' value='{par} added']"` This works for buildStatus, but not here

Step 2 (Command Line - Custom script - inline):

`echo "%par%"  # {par} added`

Is there some way to do this as one-liner, or do I need to workaround it with some other parameter that will be referenced like `par = value_that_shall_be_always_here %helper%` and initialized later in the build script with `setParameter name='helper' value='added'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference *configuration parameters* like that via an external script; they are intended to share settings within a build configuration. *Environment variables* are passed into the spawned build process; i.e. such that external scripts *can* reference them.

Taken directly from [the docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Build+Parameters)

By the way, if you in-lined the statements from your first attempt into a build configuration, they would work with a configuration parameter.

Set configuration parameter - `par = 'Initial value'`

Step 1 (custom script) - `echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='par' value='%par% added']"`

Step 2 (custom script) - `echo "%par%"`

Output - `"Initial value added"`

Comment: This is exactly the way how I configured it. I wanted to assure myself that I am not doing simple things complex.